# try-runtime no output

Tags: try-runtime

When trying to run try-runtime I do not get any logs. I also received an error in my local node:

```
2022-07-28 14:42:57 Accepting new connection, 1/100
2022-07-28 14:42:57 WS error: i/o error: Transport endpoint is not connected (os error 107); terminate connection 14
2022-07-28 14:42:57 Accepting new connection, 1/100
2022-07-28 14:42:57 WS error: i/o error: Transport endpoint is not connected (os error 107); terminate connection 15
```

Output from try-runtime

```
RUST_LOG=runtime=trace,try-runtime::cli=trace,executor=trace cargo run --release --features=try-runtime try-runtime --execution Native on-runtime-upgrade live --uri ws://localhost:9944


    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 1.32s
     Running `target/release/tfchain try-runtime --execution Native on-runtime-upgrade live --uri 'ws://localhost:9944'`
```

My node is on version `polkadot-0.9.24`, I also saw a similar issue here on stackexchange as well as on github (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11691) But I am not sure how to fix the problem where I don't have any output logs.

Not sure if it's a related problem but when I run my node I also don't receive the output log what we used to have on substrate v3. It currently looks like this:

```
➜ ./target/debug/tfchain --dev --ws-external                                                                
2022-08-01 13:38:40 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2022-08-01 13:38:42  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x4ffef2a81bdbb08f62e222fff128e5f69938b268117a1b81df76f06117f7dd8b    
2022-08-01 13:38:42 types::NodeContract billed successfully at block: 1    
2022-08-01 13:38:42  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (134 ms) [hash: 0x0679f9497911563cd0a7ee23b28334ab821175472b5541b0989dc23c334b775f; parent_hash: 0x4ffe…dd8b; extrinsics (1): [0xf713…8989]]    
2022-08-01 13:38:42  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 1. Hash now 0x847aa4d6dc62c808f2771c7de0eb6c2a815f662700f8bbd8522401648b3d04d8, previously 0x0679f9497911563cd0a7ee23b28334ab821175472b5541b0989dc23c334b775f.    
2022-08-01 13:38:42 ✨ Imported #1 (0x847a…04d8)    
2022-08-01 13:38:42 offchain worker done.    
2022-08-01 13:38:45  Idle (0 peers), best: #1 (0x847a…04d8), finalized #0 (0x4ffe…dd8b), ⬇ 43 B/s ⬆ 0
```

Answer (score 2):

As my [comments](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11691#issuecomment-1159575042) is saying, you need to pin `tracing-core` to `0.1.26`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to pin this version in the runtime but that didn't compile. When I pin it in the node it works.

Comment: Yeah, the node is the one that is responsible for printing. So, pinning it there is the correct way :)