# How to log in try-runtime?

Tags: try-runtime, log

```rs
#[cfg(feature = "try-runtime")]
fn pre_upgrade() -> Result<Vec<u8>, &'static str> {
    log::info!("Pre-check account: {ERROR_ACCOUNT}");

    let a = array_bytes::hex_n_into_unchecked::<_, sp_runtime::AccountId32, 32>(ERROR_ACCOUNT);

    assert_eq!(
        AccountMigration::ledger_of(&a).unwrap().staked_ring,
        52_500_000_000_000_000_000_u128
    );

    Ok(Vec::new())
}
```

I can't see my log.

I think this is different from [try-runtime no output](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3976/try-runtime-no-output).

I can see other logs.

```
RUST_LOG=runtime=trace target/release/darwinia try-runtime --detailed-log-output --chain pangoro-dev --runtime target/release/wbuild/pangoro-runtime/pangoro_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm on-runtime-upgrade live --uri ws://g1.pangoro2.darwinia.network:9944

2023-03-07 13:59:35.716  INFO main remote-ext: since no at is provided, setting it to latest finalized head, 0x962da9ed1763b7abaebba7f5edc3325ce35155b6f08a13a29acf92455568598a    
2023-03-07 13:59:35.716  INFO main remote-ext: since no prefix is filtered, the data for all pallets will be downloaded    
2023-03-07 13:59:35.799  INFO main remote-ext: scraping key-pairs from remote at block height 0x962da9ed1763b7abaebba7f5edc3325ce35155b6f08a13a29acf92455568598a    
2023-03-07 13:59:37.172  INFO main remote-ext: Querying a total of 9941 keys from prefix , splitting among 32 threads, 311 keys per thread    
2023-03-07 13:59:37.919  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed prefix: , took 2s    
2023-03-07 13:59:37.919  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 3a636f6465    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.057  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7f9cce9c888469bb1a0dceaa129672ef8    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.141  INFO main remote-ext: adding data for hashed key: 26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef702a5c1b19ab7a04f536c519aca4983ac    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.235  INFO main remote-ext: initialized state externalities with storage root 0x723c7d5815c574d717b7cb4328696a3899fad5ccfa825e61331e62b4556404a6 and state_version V0    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.286  INFO main try-runtime::cli: original spec: RuntimeString::Owned("Pangoro2")-6003, code hash: 1798310c6a11942c8152d0efc419c80bf9898cc582e0e8158a38c1beba9b75df    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.347  INFO main try-runtime::cli: new spec: RuntimeString::Owned("Pangoro2")-6004, code hash: acac32f457ef7640209a66460e0d58b12c93746bfe4995dc7e7199a2a046722c    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560  INFO main pangoro_runtime: try-runtime::on_runtime_upgrade    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for System    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560  INFO main runtime::frame-support: ⚠️ ParachainSystem declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(2)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(2)`    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Timestamp    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for ParachainInfo    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Balances    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for TransactionPayment    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Assets    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Vesting    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Deposit    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for AccountMigration    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Authorship    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for DarwiniaStaking    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Session    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Aura    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for AuraExt    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for MessageGadget    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for EcdsaAuthority    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Democracy    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Council    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for TechnicalCommittee    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for PhragmenElection    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for TechnicalMembership    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Treasury    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Tips    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Sudo    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Utility    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Identity    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Scheduler    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Preimage    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.560 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for Proxy    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561  INFO main runtime::frame-support: ⚠️ XcmpQueue declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(2)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(2)`    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561  INFO main runtime::frame-support: ⚠️ PolkadotXcm declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(0)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(0)`    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for CumulusXcm    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561  INFO main runtime::frame-support: ⚠️ DmpQueue declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(1)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(1)`    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561  INFO main runtime::frame-support: ⚠️ Ethereum declares internal migrations (which *might* execute). On-chain `StorageVersion(0)` vs current storage version `StorageVersion(0)`    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for EVM    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for MessageTransact    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for BridgeRococoGrandpa    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for BridgeRococoParachain    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for BridgePangolinMessages    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for BridgePangolinDispatch    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.561 DEBUG main runtime::frame-support: ✅ no migration for PangolinFeeMarket    
2023-03-07 13:59:38.562  INFO main try-runtime::cli: TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade executed without errors. Consumed weight = (500300000000 ps, 5242880 byte), total weight = (500000000000 ps, 5242880 byte) (100.06 %, 100.00 %).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I missed the `--checks` for the subcommand `on-runtime-upgrade`.

So, there were no checks running.

In the past, the checks were run by default. Now they don't.

The command should be:

```
RUST_LOG=runtime=trace target/release/darwinia try-runtime --detailed-log-output --chain pangoro-dev --runtime target/release/wbuild/pangoro-runtime/pangoro_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm on-runtime-upgrade --checks live --uri ws://g1.pangoro2.darwinia.network:9944
```